# Checking if a file exists and print the result to an excel file

Tags: shell-script

I want to create a batch file which reads the list of files and the corresponding directories from an excel file and checks them if they exist in the unix location and create a flag if they don't exist like (highlight the excel row in some colour if not found). I have putty with me, i am new to this kind of codes in unix, please help.

Thanks
gkm

Comment: It took a lot of developers a lot of time to be able to write into an excel sheet. They used C to accomplish this...

Answer (score 2):

It's much simpler (and more portable) to create a .csv file.  You can use " as a text qualifier, or any character not appearing in the text (like a tab or pipe) as a delimiter.

Add a column labeled "file_exists" where you can put your flag.  Import the file into Excel, sort and format as desired.

---

If I understand correctly, I think this is what you are looking for.  Just while you are building your .csv row, call this file and pass it the file name.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="$1"

if [ -f $FILE ];
  then
    echo -n "1"
  else
   echo -n "0";
fi;
```

let's say it's called 'file_exists.sh'

```
./file_exists.sh fu.txt  # prints 1 to your csv row

./file_exists.sh nofile.txt # prints 0 to row
```

This is only one of a myriad ways to do it.  But it will work.

Comment: thank you, i am ok even if i am bale to create a csv file, can you provide me the ssh shell script to check if a file exists and return the flag to a csv

Comment: I updated my original answer.  FYI, it's a bash script, not an "ssh" script.

Answer (score 0):

This file format is so complex and cannot be simply read/written. Also it is binary file and it makes it even more difficult to edit just from bash. Switch to text files or whatever is easily editable then it is possible, however in this case it is not or at least damn HARD to accomplish.